# delete operator does not work with the prototype property

Tags: javascript, function

delete operator works with every property except for prototype...

```
function Foo(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Foo.job = "run";
console.log(Foo.job);//run
console.log(Foo.prototype);//Foo{}

//deleting the properties using the delete operator
console.log(delete Foo.job);//true
console.log(delete Foo.prototype);//false

console.log(Foo.job);//undefined
console.log(Foo.prototype);//Foo{} ???????????????????????
```

Why does delete operator not work with the prototype property? thanks in advance

Comment: Non-configurable properties cannot be removed. prototype is non-configurable.

Comment: the real question is ... *why would you **want to***

Comment: @JaromandaX no specific reason, i am just playing around to see what i can do

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the property descriptor for `Foo.prototype` you will find it is [non-configuarble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description), which means it can't be deleted:

```js
function Foo(){}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo,'prototype'))
```

Additionally, once a `configurable` is set to `false` on a property it cannot be set back to true. So there's no way to delete the `prototype` from a function. (it's also hard to imagine a use case for do so.)

Comment: I was using Object.getOwnPropertyNames() and that returns the non-enumerable  properties as well, and i did not know that i can filter prototype on configuration: false condition. So, i thought, why not delete it. Thanks for the explanation though.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in `prototype` properties are not deletable because they're not a `configurable` property.

```js
function Foo(name){
    this.name = name;
}

console.log(
  Object
  .getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo, 'prototype')
  .configurable
);
```

Properties added explicitly, such as `job` in your example, generally are configurable though:

```js
function Foo(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Foo.job = 'run';

console.log(
  Object
  .getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo, 'job')
  .configurable
);
```

Configurable, per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

> true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.

You can define properties that aren't configurable if you wish, though, with `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
function Foo(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Object.defineProperty(
  Foo,
  'job',
  {
    value: 'foo',
    configuable: false
  }
)
delete Foo.job;
console.log(Foo.job);
```